# Assigning a RGB column array to an arbitrary number of columns in an image array

Tags: python, image, numpy, rgb

Let's say I have a 4x5 RGB image array, a single RGB row array, and a single RGB column array.

```
import numpy as np
img=np.zeros((4,5,3))
row=np.arange(15).reshape((5,3))
col=np.arange(12).reshape((4,3))
```

It is simple to assign the row array to multiple rows of the image array.

```
img[1:3] = row
```

It is equally simple to assign the column array to a single column of the image array.

```
img[:,1,:] = col
```

It is easy enough to assign the column array to multiple columns of the image array using a loop.

```
for n in (2,3):
    img[:,n,:] = col
```

But looping seems inefficient. Is there a better way (i.e., without looping) to assign the RGB column array to an arbitrary number of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img[:, [2,3], :] = col[:, None, :]
```

Comment: That does it! Assigning to a range of columns is then: `img[:, range(2,4), :] = col[:, None, :]`